# Inserting special chars (such as ' or +) into an Access database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I have not much experience with SQL, Access nor C# but I find no solution to a problem that should look quite simple for someone who has more expertise.

Basically, the user fill some textboxes in a Winform and he might insert some "special" characters (at least, special for DB strings) such as `'`. These data are hence transferred into the database through an `OleDb` connection; let's say that `string myString = this.textBox1.Text` is the value that I would like to insert into the field `MY_FIELD` of the table `myTable`.

### Starting code

My starting code was straight-forward:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + this.DBstring);
OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable (MY_FIELD) VALUES ('" + myString + "')";
comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
comm.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

The above code will easily fail in the case where `myString` is something like `guns'n'roses`, because the `comm.CommandText` will be the following string value which is not valid SQL: `INSERT INTO myTable(MY_FIELD) VALUES ('guns'n'roses')`.

### Further research

I wasn't obviously the first newbie having this kind of problem. So I searched a bit through Stack Overflow and found the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459360/insert-values-into-an-access-database-that-contain-brackets-braces) where a guy had an issue inserting brackets into the command string. Hence, I've tried to adapt my code as for the accepted answer:

```
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable (MY_FIELD) VALUES (?)";
comm.Parameters.Add(myString);
```

but this raises an `InvalidCastException` saying that `The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects.`

Could anyone please lead me to what's the best practice to insert any kind of string into the Access database without failing the SQL command due to characters that have a "special" meaning to the SQL interpreter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407685/oledbparameters-and-parameter-names

Comment: Note: the code works fine if the string does not contain any special character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in using OleDbParameter for this. Every time you want to pass values to your database engine you should use parameters. The only problem with your second attempt is the fact that you don't use the correct syntax to create and add a parameter to the command collection

```
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable (MY_FIELD) VALUES (?)";
comm.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = myString;
```

This of course if your MY_FIELD is a text field, if it is numeric then you need to use the appropriate OleDbType enum.

Said that I would suggest to change your code to this example

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO myTable (MY_FIELD) VALUES (?)";
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(....))
using(OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn))
{
     conn.Open();
     comm.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = myString;
     comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The main difference is the [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). With this syntax your disposable objects (connection and command) are correctly closed and disposed after you have finished to use them releasing any system resource used. And this happens also in case of Exceptions

Comment: Thanks a million, Steve. A big refactoring of my code's waiting for me now, but it's definitely worthy doing it :)

Comment: Hello Steve, would you mind having a look at this problem I have posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29062668/3111149)? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The [.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection.Add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of an OleDbParameterCollection has several overloads, and the ones with a single argument expect that argument to be an OleDbParameter *object*.

If you want to pass the string *value* of a parameter then you'll need to use the overload that accepts the Name, Type, and Column Width of the parameter, i.e., [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekfht847%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and then assign the `.Value`, like so:

```cs
comm.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255).Value = myString;
```

And, as @Steve said, you should *always* use parameters instead of "dynamic SQL" (which is what your first attempt was doing by "gluing" the value into the SQL statement itself).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Gord, I've finally accepted Steve's answer as it says approximately the same thing of yours + the good tip about `using`. Thank you both for your precious help!